# Why DataTables don't work with data from new partial view?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

When I put new data to table by ajax (using partial view). I have new data into table, but DataTable options (show entries, shearch, pagination) is don't work with this data. This options still "see" old data.
How I can refresh datatables options with new data, or how i can put new data to table in such a way that datatable work correctly ??

PS. When i put whole div `id="tabDiv"` in parial then then DataTables dont work (I have only "naked" table without DataTables)

My view:

```
<div id="tabDiv">
    <br />
    <table class="table" id="tab">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Kody</th>
                <th>Nadruk</th>
                <th>Data Nadruku</th>
                <th>Maszyna</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.actualCodesM)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Used)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateUsed)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Machine)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edytuj", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
                        @Html.ActionLink("Usuń", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My scripts:

```
$("document").ready(function ()
{
   $('#tab').DataTable();
});


$('#btn').on('click', function () 
{

    var codes = $('#codesCounter').val();
    var machine = $('#machineList').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/ActualCodes/IndexTablePartial',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ codesCount: codes, machine: machine }),
        //beforeSend: loadingShow,
    })
        .success(function (partialViewResult) {
            $("#tab").html(partialViewResult);

        })

        .error(function (partialViewResult) {
            alert('Error.');
        });
});
```

My partial:

```
<table class="table" id="tab">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Kody</th>
        <th>Nadruk</th>
        <th>Data Nadruku</th>
        <th>Maszyna</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.actualCodesM)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Used)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateUsed)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Machine)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edytuj", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
                @Html.ActionLink("Usuń", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

My controler:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult IndexTablePartial()
{
    var actualCodesModel = mapper.Map(dbE.ActualCodes.Take(1000).ToList());

    aCIIndexModel.actualCodesM = actualCodesModel;

    return PartialView("IndexTablePartial", aCIIndexModel);
}
```

PS2. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Why you are using ajax to load data to datatable?

Comment: Becouse I want reload only this table, rest page with other datagrids, tables must be don't changed.

Answer (score 2):

Move your script used to load Datatable to your partial view as document ready event will not work as DOM is not prepare yet.

Add below code to partial view:

```
$("document").ready(function ()
{
   $('#tab').DataTable();
});
```

Comment: Other option can be using server side option for datatable. Here is the detail for the same: `https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html`

Comment: I add to parital
    $("document").ready(function ()
    {
         $('#tab').DataTable();
    });
but this don't work for me.

Comment: Any other way to do this, this is not worked for me

Answer (score 1):

> Use below code in partial view without section script and also include all jquery, datatble, css at partial view.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //alert("hello");
        $('#response').dataTable();

    });
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old post, but I just had similar issue and here is how I solved it:

**First, I downloaded the datatables plugin from nuget package manager.**

```
 @{
        Layout = null;
    }
    //**this is what solved my issue**
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css")
    //////
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    //Your Table
    </body>
    </html>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example').DataTable({
                
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I hope this helps some one.

Answer (score -1):

I also face the same problem that datatable still "naked" after add the code as suggested by @Manprit. But I realize that the code must be as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datatable').DataTable();
});</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function () {
        $('#MyTable1').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Provide some explanation about your answer that how your script solver issue.

Comment: @mshamia, `Code` only answers are discouraged at SO. Please try to provide some explanation to how your answer solves the problem asked. this will help the OP and other future visitors too.