# How to load a Data Table in a Partial View

Tags: model-view-controller, datatables, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a partial view that is loading a data table. When I debug, I'm able to step into the partial view and watch the data table get built. Everything seems to work fine except nothing happens when the Data Table completes. It's as if I'm missing the last step to actually get the HTML to render my results.

I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671117/why-datatables-dont-work-with-data-from-new-partial-view) stating to use `$('#datatable').DataTable();` in a function, but that did not seem to work. Also another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745074/datatable-in-partial-view) suggesting to use `$('#partialViewDataTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();` in a function, but I couldn't get that to work either. How can I display the Data Table values in a Partial View correctly?

**UPDATE**:
I was able to get it to work using the `.load()` JQuery method. More .load() method information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671117/why-datatables-dont-work-with-data-from-new-partial-view). I also had conflicting JQuery libraries which was the majority of my problem. I added `.load()` function which calls my `GetAssociateResults` method in my `TOSAdjustment`controller. I have updated my original question to reflect the solution that worked for me.

**View**

```
 <div class="card-content">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div id="dvAssociateResults">
                    @{Html.RenderPartial("AssociateResultsPartialView", Model);}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




$("#pcmId").on("change", function () {
            $("#dvAssociateResults").load('@(Url.Action("GetAssociateResults", "TOSAdjustment", null, Request.Url.Scheme))?pcmSelected=' + encodeURIComponent($('#pcmId').val()));
        })
```

**Partial View**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dom-jQuery-events compact" id="table_id">
                            <thead class="navbar-dark navbar-dark bg-blue-grey white">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        Associate
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        SSO
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        PCM
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (var item in Model.get_employees_under_mgr_result)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AgentName)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AgentSSOn)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MgrName)
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        Associate
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        SSO
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        PCM
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
```